# UIModalPresentationFormSheet wrong orientation on iPad in landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I have `UIViewController` presented using `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` style. Also my app support only landscape orientation. Then I try to use frames or animations in that controller and have strange effect, like my presented controller is in `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` but transformed on 90 degree. All methods (`supportedInterfaceOrientations`, `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`) have landscape only orientation in all controllers.

Comment: are you using a certain beta ios version? If so theres an odd bug there. As in its not you.

Comment: @WarrenBurton, no, I'm using ios 6.0

Comment: OK , and you're overriding `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate` ?

Comment: @WarrenBurton, yes, it is.

Comment: Where you able to solve this? I am working on an iPad app that supports only landscape mode and my UIModalPresentationFormSheets will NOT rotate.